# Roman numerals in frontmatter are skipping some numbers

Tags: page-numbering, header-footer, front-matter

I have the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling, graphicx}
\title{Title goes here}
\author{Authors go here}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\include{title}

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

What I expect from this is to have my title page inserted at the front, then a black page with no numbering, and then the table of contents starting at number I, and the page containing the Introduction section being number 1, however the table of contents is actually starting at number II. I've cross-referenced this code with that of two other documents I've written and I'm not entirely sure why it's not working as expected.

Comment: Could you please add the preamble (documentclass and relevant packages).

Comment: Updated to include preamble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\thispagestyle{empty}` will only hide the page number, but not cause the next page to be numbered with I ( or i, or 1 ...). Put `\pagenumbering{Roman}` immediately before `\tableofcontents`.